# HP TouchPad USB driving on Android

Tags: android, debugging, usb, touchpad

Can I do app development on HP TouchPad running [CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod) 9?

I have an HP TouchPad with CyanogenMod 9 installed and am trying to build to the device from [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). The IDE does not appear to recognize the device at all though. Is the problem with the driver? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The steps on how to do it are documented in *[Issue 663: Windows 7 x64 USB connection doesn't work for file management or Android development](http://code.google.com/p/cmtouchpad/issues/detail?id=663)*.

Just in case that link disappears, here's the breakdown:

1) Turn on MTP, which is disabled by default

By going to Settings -> Storage -> Menu (Upper right hand corner) -> USB computer connection -> Media Device (MTP).

2) Adding an HP Touchpad reference in `android_winusb.inf`

Edit the `android_winusb.inf` file included with the Google USB Drivers and add:

```
; HP TouchPad
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860&REV_0227&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860&MI_01
```

after the last lines of the [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64] sections.

3) Updated the drivers in Device Manager

Right click the unknown cm_tenderloin device in Device Manager, tell it to update drivers, and point it to C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver.

4) At that point ADB should recognize the device but in an offline state which does't allow [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to run my app on the cmtouchpad. So...

5)  Reboot the cmtouchpad at which point ADB should hopefully recognize it as a device in "device" state.

Comment: Following the directions form softwarequestioneer on Windows 8 you may get an error message when trying to install the driver after adding the info to the android_winusb.inf file. Something about hash error or something, I don't remember. If you get this you need to turn off driver verification checks.  See my answer below on how to disable driver verification checks.

Answer (score 3):

Your device has several developer options that can be used by application developers when testing applications. In an effort to reduce accidental usage of these options, we have hidden the Developer options menu.

To enable Developer options:

```
Touch  
Touch Settings
Touch About phone
Touch the Build number field 7 times
```

You will begin seeing a message as you approach the 7 touches

```
 Touch the back arrow once complete
```

and Developer options will now appear under Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Following the directions form softwarequestioneer on Windows 8 you may get an error message when trying to install the driver after adding the info to the android_winusb.inf file. Something about hash error or something, I don't remember.  If you get this you need to turn off driver verification checks.

How to turn off these driver verification checks?
In order to do this, you must enter the following commands in command prompt (run as administrator)
Code:
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
then reboot  (Windows 8 starts in TEST mode).
Please keep in mind that this MAKES YOU VULNERABLE to malicious drivers, packages, blah, blah, blah.
Once you’ve installed the drivers you’ve been having trouble with, you can turn it off with these commands using the same process.
Code:
bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
then reboot

Info taken from: http://www.arctablet.com/blog/forum/archos-arnova-general/adb-driver-and-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure this out, but you MUST make sure that the option "Android Debugging" option is enabled or you will not see the extra "HP TouchPad" device under Device Manager | Other Devices.  This can be found on CM10 under "{} Developer options", which is a hidden option that must enabled by tapping the "About Tablet | Build number" seven times as outlined here:

http://en.code-bude.net/2013/03/05/how-to-activate-usb-mass-storage-and-developer-options-on-cyanogenmod-10-1/