# USB driving on Android - new devices

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I had this issue for 2 different devices till now and i hope this could help others.
I had 2 different Android devices that were not recognized by my sdk although all my sdk updates were up to date.
I want to find out a general solution for all devices that run Android OS but are not recognized by sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Using @softwarequestioneer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529648/1369566) and a little help from a colleague i found a solution that worked in both my cases.

1) **Turn on MTP, which is disabled by default**
by going to Settings > Storage > Menu (Upper right hand corner) > USB computer connection > Media Device (MTP).

2) **Adding the new device reference in android_winusb.inf**

Right click the unknown device in Device Manager, select properties, Details Tab and from the dropdown Property list select Hardware Ids. Copy the 2 values in your clipboard.

Edit the android_winusb.inf file included with the Google USB Drivers (the typical location on Windows 7 is `"C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"` and add this lines using your clipboard values :

```
; your device model
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, Clipboard - first value
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, Clipboard - second value
```

after the last lines of the [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64] sections.

3) **Updated the drivers in Device Manager**

right click the unknown device in Device Manager, tell it to update drivers, and point it to the google usb driver repository mentioned above.

4) **At that point adb should recognize the device**.

5) **If not recognized after step 4 you should reboot your device**.

Hope it helps. Worked for me on HP and Panasonic devices.