# Eclipse is not recognizing android phone

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, galaxy

Done a lot of research but still stuck.. I'm trying to run my app on a Samsung SII but eclipse isn't recognizing my device (not showing up on Android Device Chooser).

I am able to launch my app on my old MBP and my other Win8 Laptop just fine but am not being able to run it from my Desktop (win7) where I want to do my development. Heres exactly where I'm at:

-Samsung Galaxy SII (4.0.3), Win7

-The app is just an empty android app.

-Works fine on MBP and Win8 laptop. (Dev settings are turned on and everything)

-Desktop recognizing device in Device Manager but not eclipse.

-Followed these instructions https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html on both Desktop and Win8 laptop. Same setup, different results.

-I've installed the latest SDK Tools, SDK Build-tools, 4.4, 2.2, Google USB Driver from the Android SDK Manager

I've hit a wall.. The laptop and desktop have the exact same setup and it just wont work. Could really use some help please and thankyou!

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931513/usb-driving-on-android-new-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check weather you have installed the `Samsung driver` for windows,If you don't then please download `Samsung drivr for galaxy sIII`.Google driver wont work for Samsung phone like galaxy sIII

Comment: Awesome it worked, thanks!!

Link for others: http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows